# Wireless sensor for location in remote wilderness

Tags: sensor, rf, wireless

I am using a 150 ft net to try to catch a large fish. I have buoys that I would like to monitor. If something big gets in net, it will form a V. The location is very remote (true wilderness and NO cell signals) and I will be within a mile of the nets.

Is there a system I can use to attach to the buoys to monitor their proximity?  If they get within X feet of each other an alarm would notify me?

Comment: How many buoys are attached to your 150-foot net?

Answer (score 1):

The most direct way to solve this would be to put a small GPS receiver, along with a microprocessor and a medium-range wireless transmitter of some sort, on each buoy — or on enough of them to get a sense of the shape of the net.

Each unit would have to be battery-powered, and power management could be "interesting". It would partly depend on how much latency you can tolerate. Can you stand to wait, say, 10 minutes before detecting the fish? If so, put the entire system in a low-power state for as long as possible.

At your camp, you would have a receiver, and you'd plot the coordinates that the buoys are transmitting on your laptop (or whatever). The differential errors among the receivers should be small enough to let you distinguish the shape of the net. Common-mode errors don't really matter in this application.

Comment: There are 2 buoys - one each end of the net 150ftX20.  We only had 1 net in earlier this year & "something" went thru it & drug it 200 yards & the buoys were almost side by side - hence the idea that some kind of wireless sensor might help or at the least alert us IF there is another large object in the net as the buoys will get much closer together.  We could live with a 10 minute delay - we can pack in enough 'battery' power - just need to figure out what to use.  Thank you for your help - WE plan on going again 2nd Qrt next year so I still have some time & again appreciate any help!!  Jim